# How to dynamically change a sublayout which was assigned using <include/> view in android studio?

Tags: java, android, dynamic

I am using < include /> to show a sublayout (layoutA) inside a Main layout.
however, what I want to do is to change the sublayout from layoutA to layoutB dynamically in Java.  Which means in <include../> the line layout="@layout/layoutA" should change to layout="@layout/layoutB".I am not sure how to achieve this. Not sure if there is an option like view.setLayout() for .

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<other data/>

<include
android:id="@+id/id1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
layout="@layout/layoutA"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I have about 7-8 sublayouts so I do not just want to create multiple  and hide them. Which could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace include with fragment and keep replace fragment if subviews have different and complex logic if not or simple stuff you can use include and remove all views to remove old one and add a new view

```
ViewGroup parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.id1);
parentLayout.removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View newSublayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutB, parentLayout, false);
parentLayout.addView(newSublayout);
```

Comment: every time you want to add new view be sure you removed all others views